# Vertical nav using flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, nav

I am trying to create a website using flexbox. While creating navigation menu, I am facing a problem where my nav links aren't showing up vertically in smaller screens though it appears horizontally in large screens. Could you please correct me what am I missing? Here's my CSS JS and HTML for your reference.

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="brand">
            <img src="logo.svg" id="brandImg">
        </div>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div> 
    </nav>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is My **CSS code** including media queries.

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
}

#brand{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #333;
}

#brandImg{
    height: 4em;
    flex: 1;
}

#myTopnav{
    flex: 5;
    background-color: #333;
}

.topnav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #brandImg{
        height: 3em;
    }
    .topnav a{display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
        padding: 2em;
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }   
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive a {
        flex-flow: column;
    }
}
```

And my **JS**:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this JS necessary?

Comment: JS (onclick) is used to toggle sandwich icon (.icon) while viewing on large and small screens.

Comment: @UtsavRawal Is the function being called?

Comment: Yes, on the last <a> tag. That icon appears only when its viewed on smaller screens.

Comment: You made a mistake in your media query, where it is the flex container that should have `flex-flow: column`, not its items, so simply remove the `a` in its rule selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this extra CSS in your media query for smaller devices

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```